# Hibernate proxy as a key in HashMap

Tags: java, hibernate

Today I spent some time debugging an issue with hibernate, simplified example would look like:

```
Map<Cat, Owner> catsMap = new HashMap();
List<Owner> owners = ownerRepo.getOwners();
for (Owner owner : owners) {
     // cat is Lazy, according to its nature :)
     catsMap.put(owner.getCat(), owner);
}

Cat cat = catRepo.findOne("meow");
Owner meowOwner = catsMap.get(cat);
```

at this moment `meowOwner` is null because it is not found in `catsMap` keyset. It took sometime to figure out why because in debug window I see that the `Cat` with name 'meow' exists in keyset of `catsMap`, moreover, if I write an expression

```
catsMap.keySet().iterator().next().equals(cat)
```

it returns `true`, hashcodes are the same, same values, though

```
catsMap.get(cat)
```

still returns null in the same expressions window.
At last I called

```
catsMap.keySet().iterator().next().getClass()
```

and finally found out that it is `long.path.to.package.Cat_$$_jvstaea_41`, so it is a proxy and equals fails on the step when it checks class equality.
The solution is, of course, obvious, but the question is why do I have

```
catsMap.keySet().iterator().next().equals(cat)
```

returning `true`? I tried also reversed case

```
cat.equals(catsMap.keySet().iterator().next())
```

and this one returns `false`, which is breaking the `equals()` convention of transitivity.

PS: in all the examples I assume that currently there is only one cat and one owner in DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cat cat = catRepo.findOne("meow")` should return the same instance, unless your `Map` is outside of the initial transaction. If you want to store an Entity outside of a transaction, make sure to unproxy it before storing it.

```
public T unproxy(T proxied)
{
    T entity = proxied;
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity)
                  .getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                  .getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

---

You have to make sure you use the right syntax for your `equals` and `hashCode` overrides. This is an example of implementation:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof MyEntityClass))
        return false;

    MyEntityClass other = (MyEntityClass) obj;
    return Objects.equals(getId(), other.getId());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId());
}
```

**Note:** Do not use the fields directly `this.id`, prefer the getter to allow for Hibernate's proxy to resolve the entity when necessary. Also, prefer `instanceof` to `getClass() != obj.getClass()`, the first will handle implementations and extends correctly, not the second.

Comment: umm, sorry, it is not clear what do you mean by "should return the same instance"? the whole block is executed in one method, so I believe it is the same transaction.

Comment: `owner.getCat()` and `catRepo.findOne("meow")` should return the same instance. findOne probably fetches the Entity, and if the proxy is managed by a transaction, it should be resolved. A proxy is also resolved when a getter is used. Did you implement `hashcode` and `equals` in your entity? Did you use the getters in them?

Comment: yes, equals and hashCode are in place, it was my first thought, `findOne` returns the real `Cat` object when the one I got before (`owner.getCat()`) is proxy

Comment: equals and hashCode are in place okay, but do you use the getters in them? i.e. `return getId();` instead of `return this.id;`

Comment: wow, now I get what you meant, that's a real catch! :) in our code we indeed access the field. I thought that it is failing at the moment when it tries to compare the classes. so - `long.path.to.package.Cat_$$_jvstaea_41` will be the same as `long.path.to.package.Cat` in this part of equals `if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;`? bc otherwise we won't get to the part where getter is invoked

Comment: You should use `if (!(o instanceof MyEntityClass))` because getClass() won't check for implementations or extends. `getClass() !=` is too strict.